# How to get Bootstrap grid spans narrower than span1?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I have a five column grid. I've initially set them up as so:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span1">...</div>
    <div class="span3">...</div>
    <div class="span1">...</div>
    <div class="span4">...</div>
    <div class="span1">...</div>
</div>
```

The first column contains one of two icons, both of the same width: 18px. span1 resolves to 60px, however, so there's a lot of wasted space.

How do I declare a column that's 18px?

This only affects one page of my app, so it's not enough to customise the entire Bootstrap CSS, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add your own class:

```
...
.myspan {
    width:18px;
    margin-right:52px;
}
...
```

Then add the class to your tag:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="myspan">...</div>
    <div class="span3">...</div>
    <div class="span1">...</div>
    <div class="span4">...</div>
    <div class="span1">...</div>
</div>
```

Or even use inline css (but it's less clean)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span1" style="width:18px;margin-right:52px">...</div>
    <div class="span3">...</div>
    <div class="span1">...</div>
    <div class="span4">...</div>
    <div class="span1">...</div>
</div>
```

Every class containing "span" will get a `margin-left` of 30px and be set as `float:left` so you just need to specify the margin-right and width properties.

This is because of the `[class*="span"]` selector in `bootstrap.css`

In this example, I set a margin-right of 52px to keep the grid system, but you can change it to 10px if you don't want wasted space.

Comment: This can mess up the layout in responsive mode. As the width of this element won't change and others will change.

Comment: The CSS code for the "responsive mode" is in the responsive stylesheet. Obviously, this must be updated too for "responsive mode layout".